# android check for multiple Editext string and integer for empty/Null value

Tags: android

I did check some answer about how to check editext for empty, I applied but its not working. may be Its because I am sending JSON data to database through c# json WCF
here what I have done

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                      HttpPut httpPut= new HttpPut("http://localhost:4806/Service1.svc/UpdateData/Result");
                      httpPut.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                      httpPut.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");


                     JSONStringer getdat = new JSONStringer()
                            .object()
                                .key("pd")
                                    .object()
                                        .key("ID").value(txtid.getText().toString())
                                        .key("Name").value(txtname.getText().toString())
                                        .key("Project").value(txtproject.getText().toString())

                                        .key("Result").value(txttotal.getText().toString())
                                    .endObject()
                                .endObject();


StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(getdat.toString(),"UTF-8");
                        entity.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));


                        entity.setContentType("application/json");

                        httpPut.setEntity(entity);

if((txtid.length()==0)&&(txtname.length()==0)&&(txtproject.length()==0)&&(txttotal.length()==0))  // Modification done here
                         {
                             Toast t =Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter all fields", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                             t.show();   
                         }
                          else
                      {
                              HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPut);
                              Log.d("WebInvoke", "Saving : " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()); 
                              Toast.makeText(this, response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() + "\n", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show() ;

                      }
```

I am implementing it for string and I also want to use empty check for int field as well but I am new to android and don't know how to do it. 
here are the int fields

```
h=Integer.parseInt(txtviva.getText().toString());
                s=Integer.parseInt(txtpres.getText().toString());
                x=Integer.parseInt(txtconfi.getText().toString());
                y=Integer.parseInt(txtsystem.getText().toString());
                  z= h+s+x+y;
                  txttotal.setText(Integer.toString(z));
```

Thanks everyone for help.

Comment: `its not working`.  My car won't start.  Please tell me why.

Comment: even if one or all fields are empty it stores empty row in database. which I want to prevent.

Comment: You need to rethink your question.  I can see no connection between your comment and the code you have shown.  The only place database is mentioned is right here ^

Comment: @Simon, sorry for silly question. I have updated the question. If you want wcf code then I can put it here too.

Comment: OK, now I get it.  You realise that this `if((txtid.length()==0)&&(txtname.length()==0)&&(txtproject.length()==0)&&(txttotal.length()==0)) ` will only be true if ALL textviews are empty?  Are you supposed to be checking if ANY textview is empty?

Comment: ok, it means if all are empty then its going to work? I wanted to check if any field is empty.I think its going to be a better way to check if any field is empty. Can you please help me how can I check it?

Comment: Use OR not AND - `if((txtid.length()==0)||(txtname.length()==0)||(txtproject.length()==0)||(txtto‌​tal.length()==0))`

Comment: ok let me check, and please tell me for checking empty field for int as well.

Comment: @Simon, using above showing "Please enter all fields", but even then its storing data to database.

Comment: I even check it with : if(txtid.getText().toString().equals("")&&txtname.getText().toString().equals("")&&txtproject.getText().toString().equals("")&&txttotal.getText().toString().equals("")).    Even then its not preventing data to store and keep on storing fields empty.

Comment: Why are you using AND (`&&`), you should be using OR (`||`)

Comment: @Simon, yes ot worked by putting OR operator. Thanks alot for it. can you show me how do check integer values fields?

Comment: I wanted to check these fields for Null values:                         h=Integer.parseInt(txtviva.getText().toString());
                s=Integer.parseInt(txtpres.getText().toString());
                x=Integer.parseInt(txtconfi.getText().toString());
                y=Integer.parseInt(txtsystem.getText().toString());
                  z= h+s+x+y;
                  txttotal.setText(Integer.toString(z));